# flutter listview with not displaying with another widget

Tags: flutter, listview

Followings is my code to display a listview based on data from API call

```
body:onAPICall
                ? AppWidget().spinner()
                : propertyList.length == 0 ||
                        _IsSearching && searchList.length == 0
                    ? Center(
                        child: Text(
                        'No Data',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20),
                      ))
                    : ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: propertyList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return propertyListData(index);
                        }),
```

here onAPICall is a boolean value. Now i am able to show the list view or No data properly

But i tried to add a textview above the listview as follows

```
body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
              child: ListTile(
                dense: true,
                title: Text(_currentAddress,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
              )),
          isApiCall
              ? AppWidget().spinner()
              : propertyList.length == 0 ||
                      _IsSearching && searchList.length == 0
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text(
                      'No Related Properties',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20),
                    ))
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: propertyList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return propertyListData(index);
                      }),
        ]))
```

Now I am able to see only the Text and appwidget appears but the list of contents are not loading, if there is NO DATA it appears on the top of the page.

Comment: show us how isApiCall is set or managed.

Comment: have you tried wrapping it with Container ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the `ListView` has a size since the `Column` doesn't give it a minimum size.
To fix it wrap the list (and the center) in an `Expanded`

Answer (score 0):

Set `ListView`'s `shrinkWrap` property to `true`.